# construct a function which satisfied the given statement?

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume we have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f$ is differentiable for all non-zero $x$ that is $ \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, $f$ is continuous at $0$ and 
>   $$\lim_{x \uparrow 0} f'(x) = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f'(x) < \infty. $$ 
>   then $f$ is  differentiable at $0$.

My attempt : i can prove  by using mean value theorem , I need  a function  which  satisfied the  above  given  statement

I was  thinking  about this function $f(x) = |x|^{1/2}$

Is its true ?

Comment: The function you chose does not satisfy the statement...take instead $f(x)=x^2$

Comment: @Marios ur f is differentiable at x=0

Comment: Yes i know..you said tha you need such function..x^2 satisfies the statement

Comment: @MariosGretsas  im saying that $ f $ is differentiable  at $\mathbb{R}$$  \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is defferentiable at $x \neq 0$..but it is also at zero...if  such a function existed which is not diffeentiable at zero then the statement is not true..you have then a counterexample..

Comment: @MariosGretsas  that mean  such  function does not exist  when   $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$

Comment: If you prove the statement correctly then such function does not exist

Comment: thanks u....got  the  logics@MariosGretsas

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true because in $\Bbb R$ limits to some point $x_0$ can only have two trajectories at the end (the two directions): limit from below $x_0$, and limit from above $x_0$. It's even true without the condition of the lateral limits being less than infinity, since $f$ couldn't be continuous if that were the case.

To see this consider the case where $\lim_{x \uparrow 0} f'(x)=+\infty$. This means the function is growing more and more while approaching $0$ from below, and the slope of it's tangent line is getting bigger and bigger, on the way of being a vertical line. Then the function must go to $+\infty$, since it never stops growing and it has a vertical asymptote at $0$. The same goes for the case with $-\infty$ or the limit from above.

Now the result about lateral limits (it's not about the derivative of a function, it works with any function). Given a point $x_0$ and some function $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{x \uparrow x_0} g(x) = \lim_{x \downarrow x_0} g(x)=l$. Now consider $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ and take any $\epsilon>0$.

Since the two lateral limits exist and give the value $l$, we can say there must be some $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ such that $\left|g(x)-l\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<x_0-x<\delta_1$, and such that $\left|g(x)-l\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<x-x_0<\delta_2$.

Taking $\delta=\min({\delta_1,\delta_2})$ we have now $\left| g(x)-l\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, so $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=l$.

Then for your statement the first result tells us that if the lateral limits of the derivative agree and $f$ is continuous there, the limits must exist; and the second result follows (so $f$ is differentiable in that point).